# How to check for and remove a newline (\n) in the first line of a text field in actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, textarea, newline

In the script, sometimes a newline is added in the beginning of the text field (am using a textArea in adobe flex 3), and later on that newline might need to be removed (after other text has been added).  I was wondering how to check if there is a newline at the beginning of the text field and then how to remove it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
private function lTrimTextArea(ta:TextArea) {
  ta.text = ta.text.replace(/^\n*/,'');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.  I only want to replace the \n newline at the beginning of the text field though.  There are other newlines later in the text that I want to keep.  Is there a way to restrict the replace to just the first line (or even just the first instance of \n)?

Comment: Just took a look at the replace function more closely and it does the trick as far as removing the first \n.  But i only want to replace the \n if it is at the beginning of the text.  Do you know how I would check if there is a \n at the beginning of the text field?  Thanks

Comment: What I have shown you does that already. The caret (^) at the beginning of the regexp expression means only remove newlines from the very start of the text.

Comment: Sometimes, the \n will come after a few characters so might be at index 3 for example.  The script would know what index it would be at if it were there, is there a way to check at a particular index if there is a \n?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: After a few alphanumeric characters or is it going to be white-space characters?

Comment: they would be white space characters although if there is a way for alphanumeric characters it would be really useful to know how to do that as well

Comment: @Steven: the regular expression you're looking for would be `/^[\n\s\t]*/` for whitespace. The brackets indicate grouping and the star means 0 or more. You can specify an alphanumeric range with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or `\w`, but if you stick any of those in there you run the rest of replacing some actual text. Google "regular expressions" and find a primer that will help you. Meanwhile, if this has answered your question, be a good citizen and click the check mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all line breaks from the start of a string, regardless of whether they are Windows (CRLF) or UNIX (LF only) line breaks, use:

```
ta.text = ta.text.replace(/^[\r\n]+/,'');
```

You should use `+` in the regex instead of `*` so that the regex only makes a replacement if there is actually a line break at the start of the string.  If you use `^\n*` as Robusto suggested the regex will find a zero-length match at the start of the string if the string does not start with a line break, and replace that with nothing.  Replacing nothing with nothing is a waste of CPU cycles.  It may not matter in this situation, but avoiding unintended zero-length matches is a very good habit when working with regular expressions.  In other situations they will bite you.

Answer (score 0):

If you particularly want to check first character here is solution:

```
if(ta.text.charAt(0) == "\n" || ta.text.charAt(0) == "\r")
{
     ta.text.slice(1,ta.text.length-1);
}
```

slice method will slice that first character and gives your text from second character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply disable the ability to create a carriage return / new line, then all you need to do is disable `multiline` for that `TextField`...

```
(exampleTextField as TextField).multiline = false;
```

This will still trigger `KEY_DOWN` and `KEY_UP` events, however will not append the text with the carriage return.